# Benford's Law Program in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, benfords-law

I am making a program in Java to see if the Benford's Law is actually true. I am using BigDecimal, but there was an error ever since I implemented it.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BenfordLaw {
    public static int oneornot(BigDecimal number) {
        String str2num = number.toString();
        if(str2num.startsWith("1")) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            BigDecimal number = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(2,n));
            System.out.println(number);
            double newnum = oneornot(number);
            sum += newnum;
            n+=1;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(sum*0.0001);
     }
}
```

If you run this program, there is an error.
The error is in the link below.
https://pastebin.com/ShJmGjdJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program throws exception because of the following line:

```
BigDecimal number = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(2,n));
```

The variable `n` is incremented by 1 at every iteration up to 9999. Because of that `Math.pow(2,n)` is becoming so big, that at some point it exceeds the max value of **double** type. Eventually `Double.toString` (which is used by [BigDecimal.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-)) returns "Infinity" what leads to **NumberFormatException**.

Please replace the mentioned line with following to fix your problem:

```
BigDecimal number = BigDecimal.valueOf(2).pow(n));
```

Comment: @Jaden Lee Please accept my answer if it resolved your issue.